# Remove duplicate email IDs stored in comma separated format in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript variable which stores email ids inserted by user in interface.

```
var contacts="test121@example.com,lisd.lia@example.com,hunshua@example.net,test121@example.com"
```

there are repeated email ids stored in this variable.how can i remove duplicates and store single occurence of each variable?

Comment: try: `var t = contacts.split(',');$.unique(t);console.log(t);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And that's how i solved it...

```
//filter out repeated email ids
if (contacts != "") {
var t = contacts.split(',');
$.unique(t);
contacts=t.join(",");
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `if` statement there won't make any difference in the result. You can safely and effectively remove it.

Comment: ahh....actually that was part of my code and i need to check it as i am implementing some other functionality on page.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/) then:

```
contacts = _.unique(contacts.split(',')).join(',');
```

If not then do this:

```
var emails = contacts.split(',');
    seenEmails = {},
    newContacts = [];

for(var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
  if(!seenEmails[emails[i]]) {
    seenEmails[emails[i]] = true;
    newContacts.push(emails[i]);
  }
}

contacts = newContacts.join(',');
```

This will work on all browsers with no libraries and it's much more efficient than something like `indexOf`.

Comment: sorry to say but i am not using them in my application

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I just updated my answer with another option if you're not using either of those libraries. I highly recommend them though :)

Comment: I agree they're both fine libraries, as is jQuery despite all the bashing it gets. However, I generally advise against loading in an extra JavaScript library into a page unless it's really needed.

Comment: @Dan I agree it's bad to load up a whole library if you only need one function (unless it's sufficiently complex). I've found that underscore/lodash is so incredibly useful though in about everything I do that I hardly do a project without it anymore.

Comment: Agreed. Most every project I do includes at least one such library, provided it's more than a 1k page.

Comment: Thanks justin. ill try using the two libraries that you have mentioned here. however as you guys have already discussed that its not feasible to load whole library just for sake of implementing one functionality. I am posting an answer that how i have solved it.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Did you try the solution I added to my answer? **EDIT** oh, I see. You did the same thing I recommended with underscore but using jQuery instead. I didn't know you had that loaded on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example for remove duplicate string.

```
var str1 = "saas,asaac,saas,sss,sss,fds";
var characters = str1.split(",");
var distinctCharacters = [];
jQuery.each(characters, function(index, c) {
if (jQuery.inArray(c, distinctCharacters) > -1) {
        // do nothing
        alert("already exists " + c);
    } else {
        distinctCharacters.push(c);
    }
});
alert(distinctCharacters);​
```

Comment: Thanks manish. I have created an optimised solution using suggestion given by alex. refer my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force way that you should never use in production or with a large list, but will get the job done, all in pure JS without using any libraries:

```
var contacts = "test121@example.com,lisd.lia@example.com,hunshua@example.net,test121@example.com";

function uniqueContacts(str){
    var contactList = str.split(',');
    var newContacts = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++){
        if(newContacts.indexOf(contactList[i]) === -1)
            newContacts.push(contactList[i]);
    }
    return newContacts;
}

uniqueContacts(contacts);
```

NOTE: The indexOf() method of arrays is not supported in IE 8 or older. If that's something you need to support, it can still be done, just differently. (See Justin's answer for an example)

The function I gave will return an array; from there you can do what you like with the data, including turn it back into a CSV using `uniqueContacts(contacts).join(',')`

It's also worth mentioning that if you're only targeting browsers that support ECMAScript 5, you could use `Object.keys()` and avoid use of the indexOf() method *or* storing each address twice while you're looping through them. However, support for that method is slim, so it's not advisable.

Comment: Thanks Dan.brute force attack is gonna create a big problem in my implementation as i am already sending mails one by one.and implementing above code will reduce the performance. I have created an optimised solution using suggestion given by alex. refer my answer.